# Angular: ng-change mixed with jQuery not firing on second change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

Here's my html:

```
<input type="text" ng-trim="false" ng-change="onPOChange()"
       ng-model="PONumber" name="PONumber" id="PONumber"/>
```

Here's my callback functions:

```
$scope.purgeFilter = function (input) {
        var output = input.replace(/[^\w]/gi, "");
        console.log(input + ' --> ' + output);
        return output;
    }
    $scope.onPOChange = function () {
        $('#PONumber').val($scope.purgeFilter($('#PONumber').val()));
    };
```

My goal is to filter out all non-Alphanumeric keys from the input box as the user is typing them.

The problem is, if the user types "!!",  only the first "!" triggers the filtering function, and the second "!" does not trigger the ng-change.

I think it's because, the first event is a change to the input, then corrected by the callback, but the second "!" isn't interpreted as an actual change.

If I type "1234" then "!", the "1234!" gets filtered to "1234". Then when I type "!" again, it's not considered a change, because "1234!" was the last input typed.

I'm a beginner with Angular, still at the copy-n-paste level.

Comment: Try `ng-keyup` instead: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

Comment: You don't need to select the input using jQuery or any DOM selection; use `$scope.PONumber = $scope.purgeFilter($scope.PONumber)`

Comment: By setting the `val` of the `<input>` element with jQuery, the code is fighting the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Mixing jQuery with AngularJS like this is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like the below code with ng-change itself, also check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LSMg4gUNJK5l1Q0i7gaQ) with your given working example.

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-trim="false" ng-change="onPOChange(PONumber)" ng-model="PONumber" name="PONumber" id="PONumber"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.onPOChange = function (PONumber) {
   $scope.PONumber = $scope.purgeFilter(PONumber);
};
```

Comment: At this point, i do not know if my theory is correct, as to why the second event wasn't firing...    but your small change, with the avoiding of JQuery made my theory moot.  My code now works with your help.   Dhanyawad!